# Error when passing the literal string " " to a function with bytes calldata as parameter

Tags: solidity, hardhat, chainlink

I am trying to implement the chainlink keeper to my contract.
Actually I want to use the function checkUpkeep that is defined in this way:

`function checkUpKeep(bytes calldata /* */) public returns (bool /* */, bytes memory /* */)`

When I try to call this function with the literal string " " as parameter, solidity compiler (0.8.8) throw me this error:

`TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from literal_string "" to bytes calldata requested.`

I call this function in this way:

`checkUpKeep("")`

My code:

```
function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata /* checkData */) public override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory/* performData*/ ) {
        bool isOpen = (RaffleState.OPEN == s_raffleState);
        bool timePassed = ((block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > i_interval);
        bool hasPlayers = (s_players.length > 0);
        bool hasBalance = address(this).balance > 0;
        upkeepNeeded = (isOpen && timePassed && hasPlayers && hasBalance);
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /* performData */) external override{
        (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep(""); // Error here
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some of issues. The function `checkUpkeep` accepts `bytes calldata` but it is `public`. Solc generates an error with that combination.

```
function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata /* checkData */) public override returns ... {
```

The problem using `calldata` is that type of data cannot be created by the contract. It just could forward the existing data of that type.

One possible solution is to change the type to `memory`, then `(bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("")` will work.

```
function checkUpkeep(bytes memory /* checkData */) public override returns ... {
```

Other function is to declare the function as external and modify the call to `(bool upkeepNeeded, ) = this.checkUpkeep("")`, because external function are called that way.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling a solidity function that takes a bytes parameter, but you're passing in a string as the input (even though its an empty string).

You need to convert the input parameter to bytes before calling the function. Check out the [unit test for Keepers in the Chainlink Hardhat Starter Kit](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/hardhat-starter-kit/blob/1a41d42774bc4ab96a455cec35fdda4353877cf7/test/unit/KeepersCounter_unit_test.js#L14) for an example of how to do this:

```
const checkData = ethers.utils.keccak256(ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes(""))
const { upkeepNeeded } = await counter.callStatic.checkUpkeep(checkData)
```